# how to pass bearer token in python api

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, rest

How to pass bearer token in API call using python request module? Below I have tried:

```
                            import requests
                            import json
                            api_url = " "# url
                            todo = "" #Data to send
                            headers =  {"Content-Type":"application/json"} # how to pass bearer token
                            response = requests.post(api_url, data=json.dumps(todo), headers=headers)
                            print(response.json())
```

Comment: However the server expects it. Check the docs of whatever service you are using.

Comment: _Have_ you tried? The `Content-Type` header certainly isn't it.

Comment: Others answered it, but to add: Instead of manually setting content type and doing `data=json.dumps(stuff)`, you can just do `json=stuff` - requests lib will dump it and set the header for you (real timesaver, especially in quick tests in REPL)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define token before and change headers to:
`headers =  {"Content-Type":"application/json", "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"}`